Slight cut on finger during biometrics
On the day of my Canadian visa biometrics, I had a slight cut on the upper part of my upper thumb due to a razor. It didn't bleed or anything. I informed the biometrics officer about this but they said it wouldn't be an issue. Subsequently, the scans of all 10 digits were taken.
I am a bit concerned. Now that my finger has healed completely, is there any possibility of my fingerprint on the thumb not matching during immigration?

Don’t know the specifics for Canada, but there is usually quite a bit of margin of error allowed, and one or two fingers matching are often enough.

Not a problem. Fingerprint reader are notoriously unreliable and everyone knows it. We recently went to India and immigration was excruciatingly slow: Everyone had to have their prints retaken 4 or 5 times which always require a complete restart of the entire process (passport entry, etc). Eventually everyone got through, most likely not because of acceptable print quality but because it just took too long and the needed to keep the lines moving at least marginally. A Shekou port (Shenzhen) only one of 8 machines was sort of working.

Anecdote+Speculation on the opposite problem: I ended up with a few scars that'll never grow prints again on my fingers after I gave fingerprints. I never had issues entering any countries with them, but if I was questioned, I imagine because it is visible just with one's eyes that such an accident occurred, it'd be easier (than a scar during fingerprinting) to explain and convince border staff of the situation.
